# Guenberg Block Not Saving - When additional div added

Tags: block-editor

```
registerBlockType( 'cgb/icon-box', {
// Block name. Block names must be string that contains a namespace prefix. Example: my-plugin/my-custom-block.
title: __( 'Icon Box' ), // Block title.
icon: 'shield', // Block icon from Dashicons → https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/.
category: 'common', // Block category — Group blocks together based on common traits E.g. common, formatting, layout widgets, embed.
keywords: [
    __( 'icon-box' ),
    __( 'icon-box Example' ),
    __( 'create-guten-block' ),
],

attributes:{
    heading:{
        type: 'string',
        selector:'h2'
    },
    text:{
        type:'string',
        source: 'html',
        selector: 'p'
    },
    imageAlt: {
        attribute: 'alt',
        selector: '.card__image'
    },
    imageUrl: {
        attribute: 'src',
        selector: '.card__image'
    }
},

edit: ({attributes,setAttributes}) => {
    function onChangeHeading(heading){
        setAttributes({heading : heading});
    }
    function onChangeText(text){
        setAttributes({text : text});
    }
    function onSelectImage(image){
        setAttributes({imageUrl:image.url})
    }
    return (
        <div className="icon-box">
        <MediaUpload
        //onSelect={ media => { setAttributes({ imageAlt: media.alt, imageUrl: imageUrl.src }); } }
        onSelect={ onSelectImage}
        type="image"
        value={ attributes.imageUrl }
        render={ ({ open }) => <button onClick={open}>Open</button> }
    />
        <img src={attributes.imageUrl} />
        <RichText tagName="h2" key="editable" onChange={onChangeHeading} value={attributes.heading} />
        <RichText tagName="p" key="editable1" onChange={onChangeText} value={attributes.text} />
        </div>

        );
},

save: ({attributes}) => {
    return (
        <div className="icon-box">
        <div className="col-sm-3">
            <img src={attributes.imageUrl} />
            <RichText.Content tagName="h2" value={attributes.heading}/>
            <RichText.Content tagName="p" value={attributes.text} />
            </div>
        </div>);
}});
```

The problem is when i add `<div className="col-sm-3">` in save function no error is displayed and no output in shown on front end.. When remove the `<div className="col-sm-3">` the code block saves and show the output on frontend.

One more thing to notice the block didn't break in guteneditor... but no output on frontend

Comment: Hey @propatel, I tried to replicate the issue with no success. There is one thing that I wanted to bring to your attention though. You have the attributes a bit wrong. Typically, you want all `type`, `source`, and `selector` on all attributes. If source is missing WordPress will save the data in the block comments. Which isn't always preferable. Also for the `imageAlt` and `imageUrl` you set `.card__image` as selector which is not present in the markup.

Comment: [Creating a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help people answer the question, and might help you discover the solution too.